# How to sort a Map in ES6

Tags: javascript

I am trying to sort a map using below function

```
var m=new Map();
    m.set('0900','0910');
    m.set('1100','1200');
    m.set('1000','1030');
    m.set('1235','1240');
    var ma=new Map([...m.entries()].sort());
    console.log(ma);
```

Output:`{ 900 => 910, 1000 => 1030, 1100 => 1200, 1235 => 1240}`

the map is getting sorted, but when I use the integers instead of characters I can't able to sort it

```
 var m=new Map();
    m.set(0900,0910);
    m.set(1100,1200);
    m.set(1000,1030);
    m.set(1235,1240);
    var ma=new Map([...m.entries()].sort());
    console.log(ma)
```

Output:
`{1000 => 1030, 1100 => 1200, 1235 => 1240, 900 => 910}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sort()` function, when you don't supply a compareFunction as an argument, does not really work the way you instinctively expect it to work. See the following quote from relevant [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

> If compareFunction is not supplied, all non-undefined array elements
> are sorted by converting them to strings and comparing strings in
> UTF-16 code units order. For example, "banana" comes before "cherry".
> **In a numeric sort, 9 comes before 80, but because numbers are
> converted to strings, "80" comes before "9" in the Unicode order.** All
> undefined elements are sorted to the end of the array.

The numeric sort bit in the quote explains why you're getting two different sorts with strings and numbers (with `"0900"` and `900`). To overcome this, simply provide a function to the sort to the comparisons the way you want it, like so:

```
let ma = new Map([...m.entries()].sort((a, z) => a[0] - z[0]);
```

You can look into the details of how these `compareFunction`s work in the same MDN page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: You still need to do `a[0] - z[0]`

Comment: Yes, correct. Sorry, I glanced over the fact that it's a map that's getting sorted. Will edit my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here, extract the first element with the help of destructuring out of the array and compare it.

```js
 var m=new Map();
    m.set(0900,0910);
    m.set(1100,1200);
    m.set(1000,1030);
    m.set(1235,1240);
    var ma=new Map([...m.entries()].sort(([a], [b]) => a - b));

for(const e of ma) {
   console.log(e);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

MDN on [Map.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries):

> The **`entries()`** method returns a new [**Iterator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators) object that contains the `[key, value]` pairs for each element in the `Map` object in insertion order.

When calling [`.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) on the entries, it first converts the key-value pairs into strings before sorting them. That means that `0900` becomes `900`, which comes after `1235`, because `'9' > '1'` (first character of each string).

If you want to sort the entries by key, you will need to pass in a custom `compareFunction` argument to `sort`, which handles the key-value pairs and compares the keys as numbers:

```js
var m = new Map();
m.set(0900,0910);
m.set(1100,1200);
m.set(1000,1030);
m.set(1235,1240);

var ma = new Map([...m.entries()].sort((kv1, kv2) => kv1[0] - kv2[0]));
console.log(ma);
```